# overloading less than in python

Tags: python, comparison, operator-overloading

I've been fiddling with overloading operators in python and I've come across a question.

So I have a class that has values in which I want to use for a comparison.

```
class comparison:

    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    ...

    def __lt__(self,other): 
        return self.x < other
```

which overloads the operator for less than. I made conditions on other such as what type it must be.

An example would be

```
x = comparison(2)
x < 1 #--> False
x < 3 #--> True
```

My question would be how could I check on the first part of the comparison?
I'm trying to limit the first part to something specific.

An example would be

```
7 < x # --> I don't want the first one to be an int
```

Comment: As written, `x < 7` should throw `TypeError: unorderable types` EDIT: interesting, it *doesn't* throw that error on Python 2, but it does for Python 3.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga In Python 2, everything is orderable (e.g., you can compare a function and an integer number: `(lambda x:x+1)<5` -> `False`.

Comment: In `7<x`, the operator `<` is not one of the class `comparison` (BTW, pls capitalize class names, as per the convention), but a built-in operator. To the best of my knowledge, you cannot redefine it.

Comment: @DYZ So it's using `7.__gt__`?

Answer (score 3):

To do this, you can override the `__gt__` method.

```
class comparison:
    ...
    def __gt__(self, other):
        ...
```

`7<comparison(2)` will then get transformed in the call `comparison(2).__gt__(7)`, which you can override.